# What are some good books for explaining the strategic ideas of the Semi-Tarrasch Defence?

Tags: opening, books

I am looking for some books that explain the strategic ideas of the Semi-Tarrasch Defence from the black perspective. I looked online, but I could only find books on the Tarrasch defence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of books on the Semi-Tarrasch defense:

1. "Semi-Tarrasch: A Universal Weapon Against 1.d4" by Dmitry Svetushkin
2. "Play The Semi-Tarrasch! - Part 1" by Tibor Karolyi
3. "Play The Semi-Tarrasch! - Part 2" by Tibor Karolyi